General integral of a quasi-linear first order PDE
I'm taking an online PDE course where the professor isn't doing much, so I'm basically teaching myself from Zachmanoglou. The below problem was not for homework, but I'm trying to work through it and understand terminology.
Find the general integral and compute three different solutions. Describe carefully the domain(s) of the (x-y)-plane in which each of these solutions is defined. $zz_x + yz_y = x$.
In the previous chapter, we would solve an equation of the form $zu_x + yu_y = x$ by solving the system $\frac{dx}{z} = \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{x}$. I found two solutions to be $u_1 = z^2 - x^2$ and $u_2 = y(x-z)$. These solutions are functionally independent in the region $R^3$ excluding $x=z$ and $(0,0,0)$. Also exclude $y=0$ for reasons apparent in a bit.
There's a theorem in the book (pg. 60) that says that if $F(u_1,u_2)$ is an arbitrary $C^1$ function of two variables, then it defines $z$ implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$ and this function is a solution of the PDE shown above.
So the general integral would be $F(z^2-x^2, y(x-z))$, and to come up with a solution, I argue as follows: Consider $F(u_1,u_2)=\frac{u_1}{u_2}$, which is $C^1$ because the domain excludes where $u_2=0$. Then we get that the general integral $F(u_1,u_2)=0$ would imply that $z=-x$, which is a solution of the PDE for all $(x,y) \in R^2$ excluding anywhere that $y=0$. Is this correct?
Any other suggestions for solutions where we can solve for $z$ as $z = f(x,y)$? The only other possibility I see is something like $u_1 - u_2^2$ which might result in an ugly quadratic.

It is true that $z(x,y)=-x$ is a particular solution of the PDE.
It is true that $F\big((z^2-x^2),y(x-z)\big)=C$ is the general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicite equation with arbitrary function $F$.
But  $F\big((z^2-x^2),y(x-z)\big)=0$ doesn't imply $z=-x$. It doesn't imply $(z^2-x^2)=0$ nor $y(x-z)=0$.
For example in the very simple case $F(X,Y)=X+Y$ a particular solution of the PDE is $z(x,y)=y-x$ and we get
$F(X,Y)=X+Y=(z^2-x^2)+y(x-z)=(y-x)^2-x^2+xy-y(y-x)=0$
This example shows that with $F=0$ there exists at least a solution of the PDE other than $z(x,y)=-x$.
In fact they are infinity many solutions of the PDE with $F=0$.
The general solution of the PDE can be expressed on the form of various implicite equations. For example
$$z^2=x^2+\Phi\big(y(x-z)\big)$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function.
$$z=x+\frac{1}{y}\Psi(z^2-x^2)$$
where $\Psi$ is an arbitrary function.
and many others. The arbitrary functions $F,\Phi,\Psi$ and others are related.
